# Width/Height of dynamically loaded Image

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, uicomponents

I've been struggling with this problem for far to long now, and I'm guessing the solution is quite easy.

In my Flex application, I've got a component that extends UIComponent where I'm loading images at runtime and try to display them. I've tried lots of different approaches (using beginBitmapFill(), using different containers), but I can't get things to work as I want. The problem seems to be related to the width and height properties of the image, which aren't updated correctly. 
The idea is:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(sprite);

var im:Image = new Image();
im.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
    sprite.addChild(im);
}
im.load('path/image.png');
```

The image's width and height doesn't seem to be correct when it's loaded. I get width==0 (and nothing is displayed), but the property $width seems to be correct. How can I assure that width and height of the loaded image is updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a timing problem, and imho a bug in the image class, because the image class breaks the expectations of the users.

The thing is, the image class first does the downloading (and eventually dispatches COMPLETE), and **then** does the measuring (and scaling) and then updates the values correctly (resulting most of the time in another UPDATE event).

So when I first stumbled upon this problem, my solution was to first listen to the COMPLETE event, then add a listener to UPDATE (you can't just listen to update because this usually will be dispatched at least once during creation or download), but this is rather a bad hack.

I'm quite sure this question has been answered before on stackoverflow, and there probably were better solutions.

PS: also beware of the difference between width and contentWidth, just to be sure :)

Comment: contentWidth worked in my case, instead of width, not sure if they are exactly the same, but the "width" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

try it with Event.INIT instead of Event.COMPLETE